# If $x$ is not in $A$, a closed set in a Metric space then $d(x,A)>0$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

If $A$ is a closed in a metric space $(X,d)$ with $x\notin A$, I need to show that $d(x,A)>0$.
Now assume $d(x,A)=0$ then $\exists x_n\in A $ s.t.$d(x_n,A)=0$ then there is a sequence in $A$ s.t. $x_n$ converges to $x$ in $A$ since $A$ is closed in an Metric space thus it is compact, therefore the limit of the sequence is inside the compact set $A$.

Ok here are my thoughts, but are fuzzy.. I need help.
Thank you

Comment: You might want to define $d(x,A)$, but assuming it means what I think it does, if $x \in A^{c}$, and $A^{c}$ is open, then what can you say?

Comment: Closed does not imply compact in general metric spaces

Comment: And also it's very unclear to me what you are doing with the sequence $(x_n : n \in \mathbb{N})$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $A$ is closed then $A^c$ is open.  So if $x\not\in A$, there is some $\epsilon > 0 $ so that $B_\epsilon(x)\subseteq A^c$.  Hence, $d(x, A) \ge \epsilon$.

Comment: @ncmathsadist nice! Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can indeed do it with sequences if you want, but not the way you did.

If $d(x,A)=0$, by definition of an inf, we can find a sequence $a_n\in A$ such that $d(x,a_n)\leq 1/n$ for all $n$.

Then $a_n$ converges to $x$, so $x$ belongs to $\overline{A}$.

Since $A$ is closed, we have $x\in A$, which concludes the contrapositive.

Note that the same argument and its straighforward converse show more generally that
$$
\overline{A}=\{x\in X\;;\; d(x,A)=0\}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

It is known that $\overline{A}=\{x\in X:d(x,A)= 0\}$(See for instance Chapter 8 of Schaums Outline Series in General Topology). Because $A$ is closed, $\overline{A}=A$. If $x\notin A$, then $x\notin \overline{A}$ so that $d(x, A)>0$.

Comment: I guess the OP wouldn't be asking about this if that was his characterization of the closure of a set. In fact, OP's question aims to prove that if $A$ is closed $$x\in A\iff d(x,A)=0$$ which is basically your claim. Note one direction is immediate, while the other is the OP's question.

Comment: @Peter Tamaroff, Ah okay. Thanks for the comment.:)