# How to show $d(x,A)=0$ iff $x$ is in the closure of $A$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

This is a problem form *Topology* by Munkres:

> Let $X$ be a metric space with metric $d$ and $A$ is a nonempty subset of $X$. Show that $d(x,A)=0$ if and only if $x$ is in the closure of $A$.

I think this problem is quite easy to understand emotionally but I don't know how to express the proof in standard math language. Thanks in advance!

Comment: See [In a metric (X,d), prove that for each subset A, x $\in$ $\bar{A}$ if and only if d(x,A)=0](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/385127/in-a-metric-x-d-prove-that-for-each-subset-a-x-in-bara-if-and-only-i) 
or 
[If $x$ is not in $A$, a closed set in a metric space then $d(x,A)>0$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/316450/if-x-is-not-in-a-a-closed-set-in-a-metric-space-then-dx-a0)

Comment: @MartinSleziak thanks! I guess there are many questions asked before but How can I find the answer I want in the past problem? any skills in searching?thanks!

Comment: I found this one by putting [metric "d(x,A)=0" closure site:math.stackexchange.com](http://www.google.com/search?q=metric+%22d%28x,A%29=0%22+closure+site:math.stackexchange.com) into Google. You should also always check the list of related questions, which is automatically generated while you are writing a question. Some tips for searching can be found [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3258/how-do-you-search-for-duplicates) and in other posts on meta tagged [meta-tag:search].

Answer (score 17, accepted):

We prove the result by equivalence:
$x\in cl(A)\iff \forall \epsilon>0\ B(x,\epsilon)\cap A\not=\emptyset\iff\forall\epsilon>0\ \exists a\in A: d(x,a)<\epsilon\iff \inf_{a\in A}d(x,a)=0\iff d(x,A)=0$

Comment: very succinct!!

Comment: Succinct, indeed!